# Unusual space from on the top of the div

Tags: html, css

I have two strange errors: One is overlaping text that is extending over the content. I cant figure out where is the error, I have used break-word property to fix this but I think the bug is somewhere else.

Second error is that I cannot find what causes extra space between div `.category-products` and top.
Here is the link: http://mage.devpassion.eu/

I've been strugling for hours now with this and it seems I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrapped your `category-products` inside a `<pre>` element. This is causing both problems afaik.

Answer (score 2):

OMG... you used "pre" element in your code and wondering why it is displayed that way...

and extra space is from custom.css:552

```
.main-container {
    padding: 13px 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```